# PyInstaller can have unexpected behavior if an `__init__.py ` parses the sys args

Tags: pyinstaller

I have a package `dep`, where the `dep/__init__.py` will parse the `sys.argv`

```py
# dep/__init__.py
import sys

expected_args = ['--arg']

for arg in sys.argv:
    if arg not in expected_args:
        print(f"Got unexpected arg: {arg}")
```

my MAIN is

```py
# main.py
import dep
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("hello world")
```

If I call `pyinstaller main.py`, PyInstaller will import all its dependencies and run all `__init__.py`, this will result in "Got unexpected arg:"

where the args are `PyInstaller\isolated\_child.py, 1300(a random number for PyInstaller IO), 1296(a random number for PyInstaller IO)`

How to avoid this issue?

Comment: Why are you importing dep into main in the first place?

Comment: @Alexander this is just an example, in practice, `dep` is something necessary for `main.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import a module that has code written in the global scope, the code is run immediately upon import.  In order to avoid this, just wrap it in a function.

`dep.py`

```
import sys

def check_args():
    expected_args = ['--arg']
    for arg in sys.argv:
        if arg not in expected_args:
            print(f"Got unexpected arg: {arg}")
```

`__main__.py`

```
import dep
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("hello world")
    dep.check_args()
```